# linq operations on extended list class

Tags: c#, linq, list

I use linq operations on a Class (PersonCollection) which is extended from a List of objects called Person.

```
public class PersonCollection: List<Person>
{
          //various functions
}

public class Person
{
           public string name{ get; set; }
           public string address { get; set; }
}
```

Originally I was using Lists of lists of strings to store the data that this class was comprised of, and the linq operations would work

```
    List<List<String>> oldList = GetList();

    oldList = (List<List<string>>)oldList .OrderBy(s =>s[index_of_name]).ToList();
```

This would work but I obviously want to get away from using what was essentially quick code for a proof of concept

The same type of linq operation applied to these new classes does not work:

```
    people = (PersonCollection)orderedData.OrderBy(s => s.name]).ToList();
```

This is the error I get:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Person]' to type 'PersonCollection'.
```

If I cast to List it works, and that is what im using now

```
    people = (List<Person>)people .OrderBy(s => s.name]).ToList();
```

I would like to use my PersonCollection class extended from a List of people, where am I going wrong in my approach? be it in coding or general choice of how the data is being classed

Comment: Just curious, why you have to inherit directly from List<Person>?

Comment: Or why do you need a collection (as a result) - often so when 'pumping' from `IEnumerable<>` to collection - you're just using it to enumerate through. If you post more code, we could help more

Comment: @CuongLe The Idea was flexibility:Well it is a class that performs operations on a list of persons so i thought i would extend the list<person> so that i can add some functions to this class, and also apply linq operations to the class object elsewhere when needed. At the moment considering I have to cast to lists of persons apparently anyway i might just dismantle the class somewhat and make it static or place the functions in the person class as static functions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `PersonCollection` is a `List<Person>`, but not the other way around.

So you can't cast a `List<Person>` to a `PersonCollection`. You have to create a new object of type `PersonCollection`

You can do this with a constructor:

```
public class PersonCollection : List<Person>
{
  public PersonCollection( List<Person> list )
    : base( list )
  {
  }
}
```

Then you can construct a `PersonCollection` from a `List<Person>`

```
List<Person> list = people.OrderBy(s => s.name]).ToList();

PersonCollection pc = new PersonCollection( list );
```

Comment: This is something I hadn't tried, but is essentially the same as my last block of code but with a constructor to import into a PersonCollection.Does The fact that I get an error trying to cast as PersonCollection mean that I am simply wrong to try to do so? If so I would revert to having a person class, perhaps with static functions for dealing with list operations...

Answer (score 2):

As an addendum to Nicholas' answer, I would suggest creating a custom extension method to allow for a shorter syntax:

```
public static class MyListExtensions {
    public static PersonCollection ToPersonCollection(this IEnumerable<Person> list) {
        return new PersonCollection(list.ToList());
    }
}
```

As a side note, I would suggest rethinking your nomenclature: Does your `PersonCollection` really just represent a `Collection` or is it a real `List`. This might really seem pedantic but it is often worth to be really *precise* about naming in order to make your code more readable.

Comment: or just `new PersonCollection(list)` - OP can construct from IEnumerable, he needs no list.